# What does this stack trace tell me is wrong with my Tensorflow Installation

Tags: windows, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have went through and installed CUDA, cuDNN, an followed the instructions to the best of my ability. I have added the environment variables I believe I need, but I still seem to have problems.

I have come as far as testing to see if tensorflow has been installed correctly. When pull up a command prompt, type python to use the shell, I type `import tensorflow as tf`.

I then get this stack trace, something I cannot make sense of to solve the problem myself. This is where I need the communities help:

---

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Troy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 75, in preload_check
    ctypes.WinDLL(build_info.cudart_dll_name)
  File"C:\Users\Troy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Troy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Troy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Troy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 30, in <module>
self_check.preload_check()
  File "C:\Users\Troy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 82, in preload_check
% (build_info.cudart_dll_name, build_info.cuda_version_number))
ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_90.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Download and install CUDA 9.0 from this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit
```

Comment: What version of cuda did you install in your system?
Did you check the installation of cuda correctly, by nvcc -V?

Comment: nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Nov__3_21
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.1, v9.1.85

Answer (score 0):

Please try installing CUDA 9.0. the problem should be with the CUDA 9.1 version. You can download the driver from the following link :  [CUDA Toolkit 9.0](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-90-download-archive)

**To uninstall CUDA:**

Please run the following commands :

```
 sudo apt-get --purge remove cuda
 sudo apt autoremove
```

These commands should be able to uninstall cuda from your system.

**If you have the cuDNN configured to work with GPU:**

You can remove them just my deleting the files in the directories that you have copied to, during its setup.

Comment: Okay thank you! Would you happen to have any advice on how to do a complete unstall of the CUDA 9.1 toolkit? I am hoping not to completely screw up to where I would have to ask a shameful second question.

Comment: @TroyBick I have edited my answer with the respective commands. Please kindly take a look.